# What are the possible causes of "Connection actively refused by the server."?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, localhost

I have simply created a project as web application and tried to run the default page. I got this following error.

```
Connection to server localhost failed (Connection actively refused by the server.)
```

What is the probable reason? I got the same result when I am trying to use `View in browser` option. I have IIS 7.4 installed in my PC. Is it the problem there is an already deployed site there. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your connection string.

Comment: Connection string? I haven't used database at all.